# error in my PHP code drop down list to select item from MYSQL

Tags: php

i have interface which have drop down list, you have to select an item and click on submit button to view the database in mysql but doesn't work, it give error "Table 'balhaf.$table' doesn't exist"

here is my code 
the interface

```
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="list_files.php">
<input name="go" type="submit" value="submit" / >

<?php
$dbname = 'balhaf';

if (!mysql_connect('localhost', 'sqldata', 'sqldata')) {
echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

echo '<select name="dropdown" style="width:150px">';

echo '<option value="">Select</option>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';

}

echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';
mysql_free_result($result);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

my second code 
"list_files.php"

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["dropdown"]))

{
echo "ok";
}

$table = $_POST['dropdown'];
// Connect to the database
$dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'sqldata', 'sqldata', 'balhaf');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM $table';
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);

// Check if it was successfull
if($result) {
// Make sure there are some files in there
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
}
else {
    // Print the top of a table
    echo '<table border="1" align="center">
          <H2 align="center"> Report Table</H>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                <td><b>Created</b></td>
                <td><b>Download</b></td>

            </tr>';
 // Print each file
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['mime']}</td>
                <td>{$row['size']}</td>
                <td>{$row['created']}</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;' href='get_file.php?id=    {$row['id']}'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>";
    }

    // Close table
    echo '</table>';
   }

   // Free the result
   $result->free();
   }
   else
   {
   echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
   echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
   }

  // Close the mysql connection
  $dbLink->close();
  ?>
```

Comment: Well... does the table exist?

Comment: The table should likely be existing. The problem is a syntax error, since the Server is not able to read the value of $table;

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is a database error. It has nothing to do with the drop down.

The syntax you are following is incorrect.

Change

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM $table';
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, mime, size, created FROM '$table'";
```

Comment: if you can see my code i can view the data and able to download them, but how to instead of downloading deleting the data.

Comment: It should work with `'$table'` and putting the entire query in `" "` 
You should have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM $table';
```

should be either:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM '.$table;
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM $table";
```

Comment: Outright wrong or might behave unexpectedly? Parsing of double quotes that contain variables should be able to parse $sql string properly to query the database I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Put {} around your variables when they are inside strings:

```
 $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname"; //might work
 $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM {$dbname}"; //preferable
```

Make sure to use double quotes when you put variables inside strings:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM $table'; //wrong
 $sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM {$table}"; //right
```

Also, note that this is open to SQL injection attack if you let the user set the variables you are putting inside the string.